# Multiple CSV files in Plotly chart

Tags: python, pandas, plot, plotly-python

I have multiple CSV files. I want to make a chart, but it generates garbage. When I generate a single graph it is ok, but multiple graphs are not ok. 
If I see the individual chart, it works. But can not see both simultaneously.
Example:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

df_usgsn03 = pd.read_csv('Graph_Data/MME/USGSN03/mme.txt',sep='|')
df_usgsn04 = pd.read_csv('Graph_Data/MME/USGSN04/mme.txt',sep='|')

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
                  x=df_usgsn03['Measurement Time'],
                    y=df_usgsn03['VS.MM.TaLaMisconfigurationMscSupervision'].diff(),
                    ))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
                x=df_usgsn04['Measurement Time'],
                    y=df_usgsn04['VS.MM.TaLaMisconfigurationMscSupervision'].diff(),
                    ))

fig.show()
```

[image]
[image]

[image]

CSV Files are: https://gofile.io/?c=g0vztw

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because plotly is naively plotting the records in the order it gets them from the Dataframe. You need to sort the DataFrames by `Measurement Time`.

Try this:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

df_usgsn03 = pd.read_csv('Graph_Data/MME/USGSN03/mme.txt',sep='|')
df_usgsn04 = pd.read_csv('Graph_Data/MME/USGSN04/mme.txt',sep='|')

# Sort both by 'Measurement Time'
df_usgsn03_sorted = df_usgsn03.sort_values(by='Measurement Time')
df_usgsn04_sorted = df_usgsn04.sort_values(by='Measurement Time')


fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=df_usgsn03_sorted['Measurement Time'],
        y=df_usgsn03_sorted['Value'].diff(),
    ))

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=df_usgsn04_sorted['Measurement Time'],
        y=df_usgsn04_sorted['Value'].diff(),
    ))


fig.show()
```

Comment: I think number of row must be equal for line chart. Here not equal.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.
Problem is the **Measure Time** value.
It was not similar in both CSV.
I excluded second part from the measure time....Then it became ok. 
I modified it like:

pd.to_datetime(df_usgsn03['Measurement Time']).apply(lambda t: t.replace(second=0)

Thanks everybody.